# del function not working in python

Tags: python, del

I am new to python and I am having trouble deleting some elements from a list using the `del` function. I am passing it a simple text file with several lines, creating a list of the lines using `splitlines()` and then trying to delete the first few elements of the by using `del`.

When I run it however it just prints out the list without the line deleted. I can however delete everything using `del inputfile[:]`. It throws no errors and I am a little stuck.

```
class Zero_Check(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.path2file='C:\File2check\Output.txt'        

    def Parser(self):
        print('parser')

        inputfile = open(self.path2file).read().splitlines()
        del inputfile[4]
        print(inputfile)

        #for line in inputfile:
         #   print(line)

if __name__=='__main__':

    check=Zero_Check().Parser()
```

Volume in drive C is OSDisk
Volume Serial Number is F0A9-9FB7

Directory of C:\File2check

08/10/2015  16:36              .

08/10/2015  16:36              ..

08/10/2015  16:28                 0 1.txt

08/10/2015  16:28                 0 10.txt

08/10/2015  16:28                 0 11.txt

08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 12.txt

08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 13.txt

08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 14.txt

08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 15.txt

...

output -

```
[' Volume in drive C is OSDisk', ' Volume Serial Number is F0A9-9FB7', '', ' Directory of C:\\File2check', '08/10/2015  16:36    <DIR>          .', '08/10/2015  16:36    <DIR>          ..', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 1.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 10.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 11.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 12.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 13.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 14.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 15.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 16.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 17.txt', '08/10/2015  16:33         1,457,843 18.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 19.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 2.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 20.txt', '08/10/2015  16:31         2,411,884 21.txt', '08/10/2015  16:33         1,457,843 22.txt', '08/10/2015  16:33         1,457,843 23.txt', '08/10/2015  16:33         1,457,843 24.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 3.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 4.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 5.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 6.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 7.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 8.txt', '08/10/2015  16:28                 0 9].txt', '08/10/2015  16:36                 0 Output.txt', '              25 File(s)     27,538,328 bytes', '               2 Dir(s)  593,421,463,552 bytes free']
```

Comment: You really don't need a class, a simple function should do:  `def zero_check_parser(file_path):` (rename the function as you please).

Comment: Moreover, `del` isn't a function, it's an _operator_.

Comment: The file looks like the output of dir command on the windows output as  shown above and the desired out put is a list which contains lists of each line parsed by the space character. 

I would still like to know why del isn't working though for my learning :)

Comment: And use `readlines()` instead of `read().splitlines()`: `inputfile = open(self.path2file).readlines()`

Comment: Are you sure it's not deleting? I see the 3rd element in an empty string, which makes me think you have two of them, and one was deleted! Try deleting the first element ( del inputfile[0] ) and see if the it works?

Comment: It has deleted the fourth element which is a blank line (looking at output of `dir`)

Comment: Comment out the _del_ and compare the printed list. You'll see an extra blank line after "Directory ...". Remember, list indices are zero based.

Comment: Third element is just a blank line because the the third line is blank. tried del inputfile[0] and still nothing deleted.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen this may be a fragment of a larger class or it may be to follow a class signature for other reasons.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't think it is. I have checked the output for the code with del line and with it commented out and they're identical. Some lines are empty due to the input line being empty.

EDIT - Sorry! I see it now. Yes you're right! Thankyou

Comment: Side-note: Use raw strings for Windows paths when using backslashes, or it _will_ bite you some day when you try to open a file in `C:\foo\bar`, which exists, but the backslash escape mean it's trying to open a file in `C:\foo<ASCII backspace>ar`. Raw strings are made by prefixing the string with an `r`, e.g. `r'C:\File2check\Output.txt'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make a class for simple operation

```
def delete():
    with open('C:\File2check\Output.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print(lines)
        del lines[4]
        print(lines)
```